# How to search for an array within a json file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, api

I have the attached json data that I have fetched with an API from [commafeed.com](https://www.commafeed.com/). I am using it to curate my webpage here: http://faculty-fight.de/lkjfdeoijn/tiles/. I would like to also include an image of each news post. Which is within the "content" array. However, within the content array is also the actual content. 
How can I only extract the `<img/>` so that I can `.append` it to my `<div></div>`?

```
 {
  "name": "Aktuell - FAZ.NET",
  "message": null,
  "errorCount": 0,
  "feedLink": "http://www.faz.net/aktuell/",
  "timestamp": 1375222681971,
  "hasMore": true,
  "entries": [
    {
      "id": "2011990942",
      "guid": "http://www.faz.net/-hoz-7bwlz",
      "title": "Keine „Unterstützung des Feindes“ durch Bradley Manning",
      "content": "<img width=\"190\" height=\"107\" title=\"Eine Unterst&uuml;tzerin von Manning vor dem Milit&auml;rgericht in Fort Meade\" alt=\"Eine Unterst&uuml;tzerin von Manning vor dem Milit&auml;rgericht in Fort Meade\" src=\"http://media1.faz.net/polopoly_fs/1.2312835!/image/2672702860.jpg_gen/derivatives/article_teaser/2672702860.jpg\" /><p>Der Wikileaks-Informant Bradley Manning ist von einem Milit&auml;rgericht in 19 von 21 Anklagepunkten schuldig gesprochen worden. Freigesprochen wurde er vom Vorwurf der „Unterst&uuml;tzung des Feindes“. Damit droht ihm keine Todesstrafe.</p>",
      "rtl": false,
      "author": null,
      "enclosureUrl": null,
      "enclosureType": null,
      "date": 1375204740000,
      "insertedDate": 1375212854000,
      "feedId": "97761879",
      "feedName": "Aktuell - FAZ.NET",
      "feedUrl": "http://www.faz.net/rss/aktuell/",
      "feedLink": "http://www.faz.net/aktuell/",
      "iconUrl": "https://www.commafeed.com/rest/feed/favicon/97761879",
      "url": "http://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/ausland/amerika/wikileaks-informant-keine-unterstuetzung-des-feindes-durch-bradley-manning-12312791.html",
      "read": true,
      "starred": false,
      "markable": true
    }}
```

**Update**

So I worked through it and checked with some other forums and the best solution was:

```
this.content.match('src="(.*)"')[1]
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
jQuery(data.entries[0].content.match(/<[^>]+>/)[0]).appendTo('.para');
```

Comment: Wow this actually worked. Thank you so much. See the slightly messed up result here: http://faculty-fight.de/lkjfdeoijn/tiles/. I just realized though, that I would only need the url in its raw form, like this `http://media1.faz.net/polopoly_fs/1.2312835!/image/2672702860.jpg_gen/derivatives/article_teaser/2672702860.jpg`

Comment: So I found this `(((http://www)|(http://)|(www))[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|tiff|tga|svg)` on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/. However, when I try to implement it I keep getting an illegal token warning.

Comment: @John So, you need only the src attribute of the img tag? If this is so then here is the code `jQuery(".para").text(jQuery(data.entries[0].content.match(/<[^>]+>/)[0]).attr("src"));`

Comment: That is unfortunately not doing the job. My entire code is: `$("#puttiles").ready(function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "source",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (jso) {
                $.each(jso.entries, function (entryIndex, entry) {
                    $('#puttiles').append("<div class='element'>" + this.content.match(/<[^>]+>/)[0] + "<div class='story-tile-byline'><div class='tile-title'> " + this.title + "</div><div class='source;>Gizmodo</div></div></div>");
                });
            }
        });
    });`

Comment: @John what actually do you want to do?